# How to inflate data with d3.js to display an area for each datapoint

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization

I have a very simple dataset. Just three values (could get more over time) looking something like this:

{a=10, b=20, c=30}

I try to visualize these values with something *like* a barchart. But instead of simple bars I want to use some fancy graphic drawn with an area.

I only get this to work at the moment by changing the data. I read in the data in a for loop and create a bigger data set by inserting an array for the area points for each datapoint. So I have an 3 dimensional array to feed to the vis which works just fine.

But it just seems wrong to me to change the data instead of the visualisation.

This is my code at the moment to create the areas:

```
var g = svg.selectAll("path.area")
    .data(displayData)      // dimension of data should be 3D
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "graph");

pathes = g.append("path")
    .attr("class", "area") // not the cause of your problem
    .attr("d", d3.svg.line().interpolate("linear-closed"))
    .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); })
    .style("stroke-width", 2);
```

Is there a way to drop in a function somewhere in this code to "inflate" each data point into a complete area in a clean way?
Something like:

```
.attr("d", d3.svg.line( function(d){ return inflateMyDataPoint(d); } ))
```

What should such a function return? And is this the right position for something like that?

Thanks!
Matthias

PS: Example pic:
[image]

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to be clearer on what you want than "some fancy graphic drawn with an area".

Comment: It's just an 5 sided polygon. And that is the point. It does not matter what form I want to draw. I want to implement a function where I return an Array of points and these points should be used to draw the area. And it's not the function but what I do then with the function that is unclear to me. I just don't know where in the setup I should put this function. In my example above it's the inflateMyDataPoint(d) function

Comment: But presumably there should be some relation between the original data and the area? Otherwise you may as well generate random points.

Comment: OK, that was unclear. The function I want to provide takes in a data point and inflates a 2D shape and the hight of the shape shows the value of the passed data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always create a custom line generator. For a shape like you've shown, it might look something like this:

```
var w = 10; // width
function generator(y) {
  var ys = scale(y);
  return "M 0 " + ys + " L 0 " + (0.1*ys) + " " + (w/2) +
         " 0 " + w + " " + (0.1*ys) + " 0 " + ys + "Z";
}
```

You can then do something like

```
g.append("path")
 .attr("d", generator)
 .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
   return "translate(" + (i*w) + "," + (height - scale(d)) + ")";
});
```

Comment: Perfect! That was what I was looking for! Another piece in the puzzle of d3 clicked into place.